# Exception: 'Failed to start, as hybrid worker was not available when scheduled job started and last logged

Tags: azure, updates, azure-log-analytics

I am using Azure Updatement Management for Windows VMs. I am getting the error below from several vms:

[image]

```
Exception: 'Failed to start, as hybrid worker was not available when scheduled job started and last logged active at May  6 2021  7:56PM UTC. For more details, see: https://aka.ms/FailedToStartJob'.
```

When i check the status of the hybrid worker from azure portal. It shows ready as below:
[image: hybrid worker status]
[image: vm update management status]

I have check this link https://aka.ms/FailedToStartJob . But i have eliminated all the error [causes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/update-management#cause-9).

What can be the reason that hybrid worker is not ready during update?

EDIT: I have scheduled another deployment schedule and this time, the update is done. I've got no error.

Comment: So, the issue has solved?

Comment: it is not. Because i rerun again an update schedule and i got the same error: 'Failed to start, as hybrid worker was not available when scheduled job started and last logged' . It is not stable. Because the deployments are done in a schedule, i need to find the root cause.